# Count down from date picker with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, date

I could create a count down from a number, in this case 5 and it works well. But how could I put in the label the date of the date picker and count down from that?

1- I think I could grab the selected date in the date picker.

```
let wakeUpTime = datePicker.date
```

2- Next step is to put that in the "countingLabel" and this is my next problem I could not solve. Of course, this does not work:

```
countingLabel.text = String(wakeUpTime)
```

So, my question is: how to put the date of the date picker in the label and count down from that?

This is the full code:

```
var timer = NSTimer()
var counter = 5

@IBOutlet var countingLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!

@IBAction func start(sender: AnyObject) {
    // grab the selected date from the date picker
    let wakeUpTime = datePicker.date

    // count down
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:self, selector: Selector("updateCounter"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func updateCounter() {
    countingLabel.text = String(counter--)
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "count down from that?" You say you want to display a date in countingLabel. Do you want the user to pick a future date, and then have your app to show the amount of time from now until that future date, updating constantly?

Comment: @Duncan, yes you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [timeIntervalSinceNow](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDate/timeIntervalSinceNow) to find the time interval between your date picker date and the current time.

```
func updateCounter() {
    let timeLeft = datePicker.date.timeIntervalSinceNow
    countingLabel.text = timeLeft.time
}
```

Just add this extension to the bottom of your view controller to convert your time interval to hours minutes and seconds

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var countingLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var datePicker: UIDatePicker!
    var timer = NSTimer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target:self, selector: "updateCounter", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    func updateCounter() {
        let timeLeft = datePicker.date.timeIntervalSinceNow
        countingLabel.text = timeLeft.time
    }

}

extension NSTimeInterval {
    var time:String {
        return String(format:"%02dd %02dh %02dm %02ds", Int((self/86400)), Int((self/3600.0)%24), Int((self/60.0)%60), Int((self)%60))
    }
}
```

Comment: This is great! so clean and simple. If I understand this gives seconds, is that correct? Then, I should transform that to hours minutes and seconds that people can understand

Comment: I have added an extension to show it as hours minutes and seconds

Comment: I do not understand. I am very vey new and I have never heard of extensions in X code. I put that in ViewController.swift and outside class ViewConroller and it does not work ?

Comment: You can put the extension outside your view controller class at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

Use an NSDateFormatter:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = NSDateFormatter.dateFormatFromTemplate("MM.dd.yyyy", options: 0, locale: NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en-US"))
countingLabel.text = formatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

`date`holds your NSDate from the Datepicker.

Add a target to the DatePicker, which is a method being called when the Picker changes its value:

```
datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerChanged:"), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```

You have to implement the method `func datePickerChanged(sender: UIDatePicker!)` in your ViewController for this to work

**The countdown-part**

Add or substract from an NSDate wirh `.dateByAddingTimeInterval()`
For example subtracting one day by:

```
var newDate = currentDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(-1*24*60*60))
```

Comment: Updated with a hint to the countdown part

Comment: With the first part, where do you put that code? (you can take as reference "this is the full code")

Comment: The first part takes your NSDate from the DatePicker and transforms it into a String. 
Place it, where you are sure the DatePicker has a value, you want. e.g. in .datePickerChanged Delegate method

Comment: I just do not understand. I am very new in all this. I do not have any .datePickerChanged Delegate method. All the code I have is what I give here.

Comment: okay. No problem.When you println wakeUpTime, is there a correct NSDate Value in it?

Comment: @gutenmorgenuhu, date pickers don't have a delegate, and they don't call a datePickerChanged method. They are different animals than `UIPickerView`s. Instead of providing a datePickerChanged method, you write an IBAction method and connect it to a valueChanged event from the picker.

Comment: Yes. Duncan is right. My fault. Please do add an action to the datePicker: 
`datePicker.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerChanged:"), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)` and implement the method datePickerChanged

I updated the answer

Comment: I just do not understand your code what part of my code I have to substitute and where to put yours. After trying  lot of things I am really confused

Comment: np. the commitment Leonardo offers is great so stick with his solution. I am on the road atm and dont have free hands to help any further